# List of available wi-fi networks does not show up. Just 'Add' button

Tags: wireless, networking

Here's the screenshot.

[image]

It just has 'Add' button, where I have to manually set up wifi (ssid etc). I want to click on Wi-Fi symbol at top right corner and see the list of available networks. How do I do that?

Comment: What would show up if you click on the Wi-Fi symbol at top right corner? Can you see the "wireless Network"?

Comment: Looks like you can only see the saved networks, of which you have none. But I can't know, since I don't have a portable device (I have one but the video card is not recognized...)

Comment: Wired Network, Disconnect, VPN Connections, Enable Networking, Connection Information, Edit Connections.

Comment: Have a feeling that it's old wifi manager or something.

Comment: This video solved my problem: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4VVosf9p5GM

Comment: Could you please [edit] your question to include the output of the terminal command `lspci -nnk | grep -A2 Network`? Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Go to *System Settings*, then click on *Software and Updates*, go to *Additional Drivers*. Then select the Broadcom driver and apply changes.

Answer (score -1):

The above video didn't help in my case - software updates didn't provide any additional drivers.
I looked into log files under /var/log and discovered that some firmware files are missing for wireless connection. After downloading these files I could see a list of available wireless networks.

Comment: Please be more specific. For example, add the relevant lines from the log file and instructions on how you downloaded the drivers. Welcome to AskUbuntu!